# Change jQuery dialog location Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and I want a jQuery dialog box to display in the center of the current tab's window after a certain event.
The dialog is displayed based on the right event, but it appears in the extension popup window and not in the actual webpage (like how alert() does).

[This is how the dialog displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo3lq.png)

How do I change where it displays? Using "position" only changes it's location within the popup, I can't seem to get it based on the webpage.

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false,
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <title>Button Popup</title>
    <style>
    html{
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
    }
    body{
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
    }
</style>    
</head>
<body>    
    <p> Example dialog from jquery</p>  
    <div>
        <button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
    </div> 
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
    <script src = "jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

In fact this issue goes beyond just the dialog. Implementing the jQuery UI theme just for the text in the popup has a similar issue where it seems the content is stuck in the popup. The UI is statically enclosed by the hardcoded height/width of the popup, but I want it to show without the white border and not depend on manually specifying dimensions. What am I missing?

[Popup using jQuery theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUj6.png)

Comment: I recommend checking out the chrome extensions [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch), but the method you want to use here is [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get the tab that was active when you opened the popup and then you can use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject the needed code inside that tab.

Comment: I'm using chrome.tabs.query and, within its callback, chrome.tabs.executeScript as you suggested. The script simply opens the dialog in popup.html with $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); However now no dialog appears when the script runs. How do I associate the dialog with the active tab? (Sorry, I'm new to javascript)